# How does the Scholastic concept of synderesis relate to rationalism?

Tags: aquinas, rationalism

In [*Summa Theologiae* I q. 79 a. 12 "Whether synderesis is a special power of the soul distinct from the others?"](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP079.html#FPQ79A12THEP1) co., Thomas Aquinas describes "synderesis" as a habit to acquire infallible knowledge of certain first practical principles:

> Wherefore the first practical principles, bestowed on us by nature, do not belong to a special power, but to a special natural habit, which we call "synderesis".

- How is this different from the rationalist theory of innate ideas, as expounded by René Descartes?
- Why is synderesis restricted to *practical* principles?
- Doesn't this contradict Aquinas' teaching *"nihil est in intellectu, quod non fuerit in sensu"* (*"nothing is in the intellect that was not first in the senses"*)? Did he resolve this apparent contradiction?